Inode exhaustion when building lucene index
Preconditions:

Spring boot 3.1.9
Java 17
spring-kafka
lucene:

lucene-core/queries/queryparser/join - 9.9.2
lucene-analyzers-common - 8.11.3
lucene-analyzers - 3.6.2


On the server on which the import is done is:

19G (47%) space avaialble on disk
2.3M available inodes left (out of 2.4M)



Explanation how index is build
What I do is I have 7.5 mln messages on topic articles for multiple tenants (in my case there is 67 tenants). Those messages need to be read and stored on the disk as lucene index. Each tenant will have his own directory/index.
This topic, contains articles and updates to articles. Articles are kept in parent-child relationship (blocks, bitsets). Each block, is following the standard by: first are added the children, then as the last element the parent, that block is added to index by calling indexWriter.addDocuments(block). Commits are done in the background by the scheduler though. Basically reading from kafka and saving to index looks like this:
@KafkaListener(topics = "articles")
public void import(@Header("tenant") final String tenant, final Article article) {
    Optional<DocumentWithLuceneId> optCurrentIndexItem = indexItemProvider.findParentDocument(article, tenant);

    if (optCurrentIndexItem.isEmpty()) {
        indexItemCreator.create(article, tenan);
    } else {
        DocumentWithLuceneId currentIndexItem = optCurrentIndexItem.get();
        indexItemUpdater.update(currentIndexItem, article, tenant);
    }
}

Where "update" is:

indexWriter.tryDeleteDocument and
indexWriter.addDocuments(newBlock);

Instance of the IndexWriter for each tenant, are kept in the memory:
private final Map<String, IndexWriter> indexes = new HashMap<>();

public IndexWriter resolveIndex(final String tenant, final String indexName) {
    synchronized (indexes) {
        if (indexes.containsKey(tenant + indexName)) {
            return indexes.get(tenant + indexName);
        }

        try {
            final IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory(tenant), config())
            indexes.put(tenant + indexName, writer);
            return writer;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

private IndexWriterConfig config() {
    TieredMergePolicy mergePolicy = new TieredMergePolicy();
    mergePolicy.setNoCFSRatio(1.0);

    IndexWriterConfig indexWriterConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(new StandardAnalyzer());
    indexWriterConfig.setMergePolicy(mergePolicy);
    return indexWriterConfig;
}

commit() operations are done as scheduled job, per tenant, in parallel every 20 seconds (only for index-writers that have pending changes). Locking per tenant (ReentrantLock) is in place.

The problem
The problem I have, is that when importing articles from kafka, after about 1mln records, the inode usage is 100% and disk space usage is 93%.
In that moment:

all indexes (for all tenants) together have ~16GB.
there is about 6 indexes (tenants) with number of files in the index around ~300k, 14 with 10-75k files, 22 with 1-8k etc.
One of the tenants, with the highest number of files, contains a lot of .cfe, .cfs, .si files.
As you can see in my config I set NoCFSRatio to 100% to always create compund files. Despite that, after 1 mln I am running out of inodes.

I plaied with different config for TieredMergePolicy (like: SegmentsPerTier(3), MaxMergeAtOnce(100), MaxMergedSegmentMB(2048)) to no avail.
On different machine, where there is more disk space, less tenants (about 10), less articles to import (4.5mln), the entire process works fine.
But I believe there is something I can do to improve the process so it works on the other (weaker) machine as well. What could I do to deal with inode exhaustion during index build up ? any help is welcome

If this is a commercial project, compare the prices of more disk space to the hourly rates of the developers. Probably the cheapest solution is to buy more disk space.

The absolute disk space doesn't seem to be the problem but the default ratio of inodes to space which normally follows a default calculation.  If it is an option for you, then you could add a new disc/storage (or shrink the existing in-use disc) and format a new partition with much higher inode allocation.  Let me know if this is an option and what OS you are using / cloud, etc

Do you want data to be present real time for read. WHat is that latency that you are ok to take?

If you don't have it already a monitoring system that can show you bytes used over time , and inodes used over time will help you associate the activity of the app with it's consumption of resources.

try to modify your IndexWriterConfig to the following
private IndexWriterConfig config() {
    TieredMergePolicy mergePolicy = new TieredMergePolicy();
    mergePolicy.setNoCFSRatio(1.0);
    mergePolicy.setSegmentsPerTier(2);
    mergePolicy.setMaxMergedSegmentMB(4096); 
    IndexWriterConfig indexWriterConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(new StandardAnalyzer());
    indexWriterConfig.setMergePolicy(mergePolicy);
    indexWriterConfig.setUseCompoundFile(true); 
    indexWriterConfig.setRAMBufferSizeMB(128); 

    return indexWriterConfig;
}


